# Graph has at least two colorings

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

Let $k \geq 2$ and $G$ be an incomplete graph that is $k$-colorable and has less than $(k-1)|V(G)|-{k\choose 2}$ edges.

I want to show that $G$ has at least two $k$-colorings. It looks really simple but I just don't know how to start here.

Comment: How do you distinguish colorings?

Comment: Two colorings are the same if their partitions of |V(G)| are the same.

Comment: Take $k=2$ and $G$ connected. What type of graph do you have ? How many 2-colorings do you have ?

Comment: @caduk Such a graph would have at least $|V(G)|-1$ edges so $G$ cannot be connected. In that case you could double the number of colorings for each component so in total $2^c$ colorings (c is the number of components)

Comment: A tree have $|V(G)|-1$ edges

Comment: @caduk yes, so in the case of $k=2$ G should have less than $|V(G)|-1$ edges so G cannot be a tree

Comment: Sorry, my french habit that less than means $\leq$...

Comment: This is an interesting problem. You can attack it with Kempe chains

Comment: @caduk ok thank you. I just noticed that I can reduce this problem to k being the chromatic number, otherwise I would just have to use a minimal coloring and add one color. Then the only way kempe chains would not give another coloring is that every kempe chain contains all vertices of these colors. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes. Then you just need to lower bound the number of edges in the graph by summing over Kempe chains using double counting.

Comment: @caduk I tried this: I can lower bound the A,B-Kempe chain by |A| or |B| but I only get $2|E(G)| \geq (k-1)|V(G)|$ if I understand double counting correctly. Do I miss something here?

Comment: No, your lower bound is incorrect, a kempe chain is at least a tree induced by $A\cup B$. You then need to sum over the $\binom{k}{2}$ possible kempe chains.

Comment: @caduk I posted a full solution to my problem. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the great help in the comments I could find a solution.

If $k$ is greater than the chromatic number you can take a minimal coloring and change the color of one of the vertices to one of the unused colors.

Now let $k$ be the chromatic number and $\mathscr{C} = \{C_1, \dots,C_k\}$ be a $k$-coloring of $G$ (partition of $|V(G)|$). Assume that there is no other $k$-coloring, we want to lead this to a contradiction. This means that any Kempe chain for two colors must contain all of the vertices of these colors. Therefore, the A,B-Kempe chain is at least a tree induced by $A\cup B$. Every edge can only be in one chain so we can sum over the edges in every Kempe chain to get $|E(G)|$. A tree T has $|V(T)|-1$ edges and there are ${k\choose 2}$ chains so by summing over the Kempe chains we get:

$$\begin{align*}|E(G)|&\geq \sum_{i=1}^k \sum_{j=i+1}^k(|C_i\cup C_j|-1)\\
&=(\sum_{i=1}^k \sum_{j=i+1}^k|C_i|+| C_j|)-{k\choose 2}\\
&=(k-1)\sum_{i=1}^k|C_i|-{k\choose 2}\\
&=(k-1)|V(G)|-{k\choose 2}\\
&>|E(G)|\end{align*}$$

So there are at least two colors with two different (and not connected) chains, swapping the colors in on of the chains gives a second $k$-coloring.